# Where can I get the latest Ubuntu Alpha or Beta?

Tags: release-management, testing

I'd love to test the latest Ubuntu alpha/beta (otherwise known as "Ubuntu+1"), but I can't find it.

Where can I find download for the pre-releases of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 25):

Daily snapshots are always available here:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

This information will be useful to you:

- [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Though it is an alpha/beta now don't run it on a machine you need to be working all the time.

Answer (score 5):

It is not released yet, check the [Ubuntu testing](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing) page for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version is always available for [download here](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing).

Please note that this is ***unstable***, so things will break. So, for more information, take a look at this question - [There's an issue with an Alpha Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 2):

None of the features proposed for natty are implemented as of yet. you wouldnt get much fun testing it. i would advice you to wait till beta 1.

Compiz 0.9.2 has been added to daily image. I am off to test. Sadly virtualbox seems to give problems. might work on testdrive