# How to upgrade to the development version of Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

How do I upgrade Ubuntu 10.10 to the latest development version of Ubuntu 11.04?