# How do I try Unity from Natty?

Tags: unity, 11.04

How can I try the newest codebase of Unity, so that I can send bug-reports and feature requests to the Unity developers?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1

Answer (score 2):

Install Natty on a new partition and keep updating.

Comment: that's what I'm doing, but nothing gets updated!! My /etc/apt/sources.list has the following:

Comment: it has all of the natty lines in them, but when I do an "apt-get update " and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" it doesn't upgrade anything...

Comment: Have you filed a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to download the newly commited code using bazaar, this can be done by downloading the unity branch from Launchpad, just execute the following command in your desired destination, having Bazaar (bzr packave) installed

```
bzr branch lp:unity
```

To install Bazaar:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
```

You should then configure and build the code, for doing this you should read the `README` and `INSTALL` files.