# How do I upgrade to the development release without graphics?

Tags: command-line, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

There was a question
[How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

The solution is to use `update-manager -d` and that pop-up a GUI.

I don't have access to graphics.

I'm hoping that the upgrade would solve my graphics (x-org, ...) issues.

How can I upgrade from the console?

Comment: The question you already found is also [answered for CLI only](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1/22808#22808)