# Are daily builds of Ubuntu stable enough for general desktop usage?

Tags: release-management

Are the [daily development builds of Ubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/)  (Known as [Ubuntu+1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)) stable and mature enough for general desktop usage?

Also, if I install the latest daily build today, will it notify for the update of the stable release when Ubuntu+1 is officially announced?

Comment: I am installing today, 2017-04. I was wondering whether to go with 16.04 LTS, 16.10 or 17.04 nightly build.  Went with 17.04 nightly and so far so good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, remember that a development build of Ubuntu is exactly that - a development build. So things **will break**.

With that being said, [your mileage may vary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

Second, if you run `update-manager` (or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`) fairly frequently (Read: Daily), on release day in theory you will be on the same Ubuntu as everyone else - although I don't recommend using a Ubuntu+1 install for daily usage, even after release day.

It's better to just start fresh, or to upgrade your previous Ubuntu stable installation, if you're into that kind of thing.

Lastly (and I can't stress this enough) if you're not a developer, you really *shouldn't* be running the development version.

Comment: hmm ok, I thought that it was using different repos (that's why I've asked about the update).

Comment: Nope. 11.04 uses the 11.04 repos. The *contents* (packages) will change, but the repos won't.

Comment: I think it's good to go. The desktop team are doing an excellent job of identifying top issues and nailing them. Everyone I chat with on a daily basis is on Natty, so I'd be taking bullets if it were short :-)

Comment: @Mark Shuttleworth I myself am using Natty (As I said), and I haven't had any issues within the past week or so that I didn't cause myself though tinkering. So, while I agree that Natty is good to go, it technically isn't ready for daily, "average joe" use yet. :-)

Comment: I think this answer needs a couple of clarifications: (1) *"on release day in theory you will be on the same Ubuntu as everyone else"* seems contradictory to *"I don't recommend using a Ubuntu+1 install for daily usage, even after release day"*. Why don't you recommend it, if the end result is the same? (2) Why do updates need to be applied *"fairly frequently (Read: Daily)"* to end up with the same Ubuntu? What is the difference between e.g. updates applied on day 1 and day 7 vs updates applied on days 1,2,3,4,5,6,7? Surely the end result should be the same?

Answer (score 2):

The problems with daily builds during this phase of the release cycle are typically installation failures for one reason or another, rather than problems once you actually start trying to use it on the desktop.  If it installs fine for you, you can continuously upgrade to the stable release and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

How useful the development daily images are depends very much on which part of the development cycle we're in.  During the alphas, there is a high degree of churn and daily breakage is frequent.  They are very useful for developers, but not recommended for general desktop users.   As we get to the beta phases of a release,  things are generally much more stable and usable for general desktop users to try things out.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, whether a daily build is stable enough for daily usage mostly depends on your ability to troubleshoot problems. Secondly, the question was asked late April 2011, seven days before release day of Ubuntu 11.04. If you're seven days away from release day, if you have a working OS on your computer, I'd recommend waiting until release day. If you don't have a working OS on your computer, you're closer to release day than to the date the most recent alpha/beta was released, go for it.

What I recommend is to check the release schedule. If the feature freezes haven't kicked in yet, you could end up with very unpredictable results.

Another thing you can do is run the daily build as a virtual machine (virtualbox, vmware, etc.), and set it up as you normally would (extra repositories, run updates, etc.). Once you've tested it as a virtual machine and are confident that you can install it to your computer without trouble, go for it. Be warned, you may end up with irreversible problems where the easiest solution is to do a fresh install.

Lastly, as always, back everything up before you consider reformatting your OS partition.

Answer (score 1):

i been using daily builds and beta on 14.04 and so far keeping my fingers crossed and knocking on my fake wood. So far the 14.04 is very stable i get some crashes as known for pre-releases but they been more stable than previous versions of ubuntu.