# Does auto updating work across major versions?

Tags: upgrade, updates, release-management

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, and installing regular automatic updates. Since 11.10 is out, I expected it will be auto upgraded, but no, I'm still:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 11.04
```

Now I want for example [modal dialogs](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/modal-dialogs-land-ubuntu-11-10/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20d0od%20%28Omg!%20Ubuntu!%29), but if I understand well, update will get only 11.10 users.

Is Ubuntu auto updating major versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

11.10 is not out yet. only the alpha has been released and the final version will be released in october and you will notified through the update manager when that happens .

Comment: Will I be able to update without any harm? Thanks.

Comment: @umpirsky most probably .

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, Ubuntu's version numbers always refer to the year of release, and the month of release. So 11.10 means the 10th month (october) of the year 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Above is correct but better to run the official upgrade than just change your sources to the next version.

Run this from a terminal:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

This will give you an upgrade option to the next version at the top of the updates window. Click this and follow instructions.

Answer (score -1):

If You want an alpha release, just change your sources.list in /etc/apt and replace all natty with oneiric. Then type sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.
After upgrade completes, you should have 11.10 release.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for an official release. But it's good to know this.

Comment: This isn't correct, please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1