# What version of varnish should I run on 11.04? 

Tags: server

I went to ubuntu's main site and downloaded the latest LTS version 11.04.

Now I'm trying to install varnish on it, and following the steps on the downloads page for Ubuntu I added the new repo but it has /natty/ in the url, and when I try and to an apt-get update I noticed there is a 404 error since that url doesn't exist.

I see they only have this distro's with packages:

```
http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/dists/
```

Its LTS one of these, or is LTS considered Natty or ?

Comment: actually 8.04 is still LTS for servers and so is 10.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current LTS is version 10.04 - not 11.04.

The repo you have indicated only has packages for 10.04.

However - you dont need the external repository in your question.  You also dont need to reinstall the LTS unless you want the 5 years support rather than the 18months for Natty.

To install varnish:

```
sudo apt-get install varnish
```

i.e. you don't need to reinstall the LTS.

Version 3 on varnish is packaged for 11.10 which is to be released in a couple of weeks (at the time of writing this).

Thus - three choices -

1. wait a couple of weeks and upgrade to 11.10
2. install the LTS now and add the varnish-cache repo
3. force an upgrade to the 11.10 beta immediately to help out testing i.e.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Comment: well I did apt-get -s install varnish and it shows version 2.1.4 and I want the latest stable which is 3.0.1

Comment: can't I just add the repo and package? or there are issues with that, I don't get it :)

Comment: The repo doesnt have a natty version - there are ways to "force" an install - but you usually get into major packaging issues.  The recommended way is to install from the standard repos' or via a PPA - I havent found a PPA with v3 (v3 only came out at the end of August).

Comment: I see ok, thanks then I guess I'll try the upgrade.

Comment: wait, so the people at varnish created a package for a yet to be released os?  that's interesting!

Comment: Probably not - its open-source software, so its likely the good folk at either debian/or the oneiric devs themselves have recompiled to make it easier for 11.10 to pull in a version that installs correctly.

Comment: so once I do this upgrade, when the official is release, I can update then again right to be more stable?

Comment: just keep on updating - you will automatically be on the latest stable version.

Comment: didn't work, doing an apt update I got: Failed to fetch http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/varnish-3.0/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: ok - you have now upgraded to 11.10?  Then remove (from software sources) the varnish-cache repo.  You can now install varnish - in the standard repositories it is version 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases, Ubuntu 10.04 is the current LTS version. 11.04 is the current supported stable version for which support will end in October 2012. The 10.04 LTS version is supported till April 2015 (for **servers only**, desktop is supported till April 2013).

Answer (score 0):

To install Varnish on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update; apt-get install curl nano
sudo curl http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/GPG-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo "deb http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ precise varnish-3.0" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update; apt-get install varnish
```