# 12.04 already available through update-manager: it's a bug?

Tags: updates, lts

- ALT + F2
- update-manager -d

this is what i see on my desktop ( Ubuntu LTS 10.04.3 amd64 desktop ):

[image: update manager screen]

It's italian, that means ubuntu 12.04 is already available and suited for production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually no - its not ready...

The command you have used tests to see if the next development release should be presented as an option to upgrade to.

> man upgrade-manager
>
> -d, --devel-release
>                 Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible

See the linked question for more information.

If you are currently on Natty looking to upgrade to Oneiric, then also see the linked question below on how to do this N.B. is the same process as any upgrade to the next stable release.

The stable LTS v12.04 will be released in April 2012.

---

Linked Question:

- [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)
- [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10-04-or-10-10-to-11-04)

Comment: ok, thanks, just for the record i discovered that is also possible to select different channels and "types" of releases with the help of the update-manager using the settings button.