# Ubuntu system updates

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but I am wondering how can you update from 12.04 to 12.10? Do you need to download the cd or you can simply update it from the update manager? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd wait until it is officially released and then use the update manager.

Comment: In addition, usually you don't really need to upgrade. If stability matters it is often a better idea to stay for a while with the current release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

To upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a desktop system:

Open Software Sources.

Switch to the Updates tab and set Notify me of a new Ubuntu version to For any new version.
Press Alt+F2 and type in `update-manager -d` (without the quotes) into the command box.
Update Manager should open up and tell you: `New distribution release '12.10' is available.`
Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

To upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a server system:

Ensure that `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` includes `Prompt=Normal`.

Install the `update-manager-core` package if it is not already installed.

Launch the upgrade tool with the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.
Follow the on-screen instructions.