# Why can't I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 using Update Manager?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I'm aware of the [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1) question and this is NOT a duplicate.

On my laptop running Ubuntu 12.10, when running `sudo update-manager -d`, I'm getting "The software on this computer is up to date".

Running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` starts the upgrade procedure

Is it a (temporary) bug in Update Manager which is going to be fixed or is it a change which makes our "canonical" answer obsolete? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you need to use sudo for upgrading using update-manager.

Comment: @jokerdono: I tried running `update-manager -d` without `sudo` - it still does not see the new release.

Comment: Look, you will need to have the *software-source* correctly configured in order to get the updates. Otherwise, you will get the "Your computer is up-to-date" message.

Comment: @Sergey could you add your `sources.list` file? Be sure that in the Software Sources, Updates tab, Release Updates option is in "Normal Releases".

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Settings --> Software & Updates, then in the Software & Updates window, go to the Updates tab. Change the option Notify me of a new Ubuntu version to **For any new version.** Then go back and run update manager.

Basically the default setting only lets you upgrade to LTS versions and 13.04 is not LTS.