# Upgrading from 12.04 to 13.10 ( Unanswered questions )

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade to 13.10 mainly because I want my computer to recognize my Samsung GS4. I am pretty happy with Ubuntu as it's faster then windows and way more everything, tough it's hard sometimes with compatibility.

I want to know what will happen:

-The new stuff ( ok please not everything )

-Will this erase stuff I have right now ? ( like folder with music, background, etc...)

-How long will it take ?

-How should I do it ?

Comment: This site prefers questions with single focus. Please don't club several questions into one.

Comment: Those other questions part should be question on their own. But please try to make sure that those wouldn't be duplicated.

Comment: Oh sorry then I'll delete my other questions ^^

Comment: Either scale down your question to just one or it will be probably closed as too broad.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/322252/upgrading-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-13-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not upgrade directly from 12.04 to 13.10.
You have to do all the steps in between as this answer explains: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

So in your case from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 to 13.10.
As this is neither practical nor desirable I would suggest that you either make a backup of your `/home/YOUR_USERNAME` folder to keep all your music and other personal files save and then download the Ubuntu 13.10 image to make a fresh install.
Or the other thing you could do is wait till Ubuntu 14.04 LTS comes out in april and then do an update.

The good thing about the second possibility is that you don't have to reinstall your system because you can do direct system upgrades between LTS (Long-Term Support) releases.

Comment: Thanks ! I will do a direct upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 :) Tough can I lose anything in the process ?

Comment: As far as my experience goes no. The worst thing that could happen is the upgrade messing up your graphic drivers and leaving you with a system that won't boot to the graphical interface...which would be annoying but not unsolvable. But just to be safe I would back up my important data anyways.

Comment: 13.04 is no longer supported, would that be a problem during the upgrade?

Comment: @Dan look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/368068/how-will-people-upgrade-from-12-10-to-later-releases-after-13-04-is-eol