# MTP support on Ubuntu 12.04 using Ubuntu 14.04 repositories

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, mtp

I have Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 32-bit installed on one of my laptops and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit installed on the other. I think the latter version of Ubuntu has native MTP support as I did not install any package by myself and I was able to do file manipulations after having the table auto mounted when I plugged it in(Samsung GT-8010 Galaxy Note).

Now I think if it is possible to have `MTP` support on Ubuntu 12.04.5 32-bit using the repositories of the latest Ubuntu or something like that. I remember that I was able to get the support somehow on the previous version of Ubuntu but problems such as file transfer halting in the middle of the operation and not being able to execute/open files inside the tablet were present, thus I thought I did something wrong. I would appreciate it if someone could aid me in this process. Or should I just install Ubuntu 14.04 instead?

Comment: NEVER mix 12.04 and 14.04 repos or software unless you REALLY know what you're doing - you're guaranteed to nuke your system if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **14.04 has native MTP support**

Correct. As of 13.04 to be exact. From the [release notes](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/gvfs/+changelog):

```
gvfs (1.15.2-0ubuntu1) raring; urgency=low

  * debian/watch: Look for development releases, too.
  * New upstream release:
    - Add new MTP backend. In particular this can access Android 4.0 devices
      which do not support the USB Mass Storage interface any more.
      (LP: #903422)
```

> **Now I think if it is possible to have MTP support on Ubuntu 12.04.5 32-bit using the repositories of the latest Ubuntu**

During 13.04 there was an upgrade path for 12.10 and 12.04. [webupd8.org had a article on it](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html). This was the way to get it into 12.04 but it might not work anymore ...

> Upgrade Gvfs in Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 to get Android 4.0 support for devices which don't support USB Mass Storage interface
>
> The packages in this PPA may be unstable. Use the PPA at your own risk! There are instructions on how to revert the changes at the bottom of the post.
>
> 1. To add the Gvfs (and libmtp) PPA created by the Gvfs MTP backend developer in Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10, use the following commands:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
    sudo apt-get update
```

> 2. Then, launch Software Updater (previously known as Update Manager) and install the available updates.

Might be worth an attempt.

> **Or should I just install Ubuntu 14.04 instead?**

Yes, if there is nothing else holding you back that is I would myself have it upgraded to 14.04. There is an upgrade path for 12.04->14.04. This should be the easiest method: https://askubuntu.com/a/12910/15811

Comment: Thanks for your through answer so upgrading to 14.04 is the best way in your opinion since I have no particular reason to stick with the older version. By the way I would like to install a 64-bit Ubuntu instead of the 32-bit version; therefore I think I need to perform a full reinstall, is it correct?