# How to Upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, 15.04

I'm looking for a way to upgrade 14.10 to 15.04 - from the internet only (i.e. without using external media).

I've already tried `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: possibly - however it is stil unstable so you may not get many benefit from it (it might also be better to wait for the beta release) - see: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/01/ubuntu-15-04-alpha-2-downloads

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Answer (score 92):

Ubuntu 15.04 is not available yet and will be available in April. If you really want to test it you can download the daily build iso from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/) although this is highly unstable now.

After the release you can upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 by running the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I would not recommend this but if you  really want to upgrade to the latest development release:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

---

**EDIT :**

As Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) **has been released on 23rd April, 2015**, you can upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 easily now.

- At first make sure the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` has the line:

  ```
  Prompt=normal
  ```
- Now run the following command:

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Comment: I'm aware, but I assumed that there was a way to upgrade from within the system.

Comment: @MasonVanderpool: Check my edits..

Comment: You can call it without `sudo` and it will ask for the password in the process.

Comment: In my case (14.04, fully updated) the only way to make **do-release-upgrade** react was to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade` _after_ changing to `Prompt=normal`

Comment: in my case Prompt=lts. I am unable to edit it since its read-only.  I am running 14.04LTS. how can I upgrade to 15.04?

Comment: @AnoopSS You need to be `root` to edit the file..just use `sudo` before the command to impersonate `root`

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 14.04. When I run "sudo do-release-upgrade", how'll it know  whether I want to upgrade to 14.10 or 15?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp You can't directly upgrade to 15.04, you need to upgrade to 14.10 first then you can upgrade to 15.04. I would suggest you to stick with 14.04 ad it's an LTS release and will be supported till april,2019.

Comment: @heemayl, yes, but 15.04 some interesting features, I want to try it.