# Apt-get crash on any install operation

Tags: apt

I have weird issue with ubuntu 14.04. When I trying update my system or install any software I have an error

```
$ sudo apt-get install 4digits
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    4digits : Depends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
    linux-tools-3.13.0-53 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

So when I try start "sudo apt-get -f install" I have error again

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (3.13.0-53.89) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb (--unpack):
    trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/perf', which is also in package linux-   lts-vivid-tools-common 3.19.0-18.18~14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is [confirmed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-vivid/+bug/1455014). As packages require vivid tools, [upgadring to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/588022/249531) may be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair your package management via

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-tools-3.13.0-53 linux-tools-common
```

Eventually remove the other app too

```
sudo apt-get purge 4digits
```