# Unable to locate package mongodb-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, 14.10, mongodb

I try to install `mongodb` client for `c++`, but get this error message `Unable to locate package mongodb-dev`, when I do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-dev
```

even though `mongodb-dev` seems to exists, judging by this Ubuntu [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/precise-updates/i386/mongodb-dev/filelist). So, my question is how to install `mongodb-dev`?

Comment: Whats the output of `lsb_release -r` ?

Comment: The output is `14.10`

Comment: 14.10 is off-topic now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [upgrade to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588019/how-to-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04/588022#588022) as soon as possible as [14.10 has reached its End of Life (EOL) yesterday (23rd July, 2015)](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-July/000197.html).

Note that [mongodb-dev is not available in 14.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mongodb-dev), your best bet would be to [download the .deb file from launchpad](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/170834766/mongodb-dev_2.4.9-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) and the install it with :

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

Then you need to satisfy the dependency (`libboost-dev`) with :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Otherwise you can use `gdebi` to do the whole work for you (install `gdebi` first) :

```
sudo gdebi package_name.deb
```

Or open the `.deb` file with *Ubuntu Software Center* which will take care of everything for you.

Comment: I wonder if there exists any up to date tutorial of installing mongodb driver for c++ in Ubuntu. Since what i've seen by now (after scanning literally thousands of threads) does not work. And this is the first time I hear about .deb file from launchpad for instlling the driver. I have not heard about it.

Comment: Nice, works also with Vivid =)

Comment: What is Vivid?.

Comment: @Jacobian `vivid` is the codename for Ubuntu 15.04..

Comment: @Jacobian you should upgrade to 15.04 ASAP..also from now on if any package is not available in the repos you should start searching for any `.deb` file e.g. in launchpad, then as a last option you can compile from source yourself..

Comment: arm64 version for those who don't want i386: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mongodb/mongodb-dev_2.4.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the answer just because you asked again after the installation of Ubuntu 15.04

The package `mongodb-dev` is not longer in the Ubuntu Standard Repositories. The latest release was [`2.4.9-1ubuntu2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mongodb-dev) in Trusty.