# Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I was viewing this([How to Upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588019/how-to-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04)) answer on how to upgrade. what I wanted to know is there are some commands which are depreciated in the version 15.04, so if i upgrade will they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04.

One only can upgrade from a LTS release to next regular release during the time of it's support or to next LTS. Ubuntu 14.10, the next release after 14.04 is outdated and you can NOT upgrade to it.

So, you should wait for six months when Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will come out, or clean install Ubuntu 15.10 over the current installation of Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please don't upgrade to 15.04 - it will be out of support soon!
   [Use this link to 15.10 instead](https://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/).
2. For more information read the release notes for 15.10 [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes).
   There you'll get all original information!