# No /sbin/init after upgrading to ubuntu 15

Tags: boot, upgrade, 15.04

I wanted to upgrade my system from 14 to 15, so along [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588019/how-to-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04) instructions, I changed the line to `Prompt=normal` and ran the upgrade command. A couple of hours later, I decided to reboot and check out the new ubuntu. However, it froze on shutdown, and I had to do a hardware shutdown. And when I tried to reboot, I got the `/sbin/init` missing error. I tried many of the other solutions, but none worked.

And when I booted with a GParted live CD, and mounted my old file system, I saw that all my files were intact.

However, my `/sbin/init` and `/sbin/shutdown` were *actually* missing.

What should I do to get my system back and running? I can get a live/installation CD if need be, but don't have one on hand.

Comment: Do you have `/lib/systemd/systemd` and `/sbin/systemctl`?

Comment: @muru I have a bunch that are `/lib/systemd/systemd-<stuff>` but nothing that's just `/lib/systemd/systemd`

Comment: @muru I have no `/sbin/systemctl`, but I have `/sbin/sysctl`

Comment: If you can setup a chroot on your old filesystem, do that, and run `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get install -f`. That might continue the interrupted upgrade. If not, run `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @muru what's a chroot and how do I set one up?

Comment: A chroot is when you use another directory as `/`, in effect you see the filesystem as if you'd booted into it. See http://askubuntu.com/a/28100/158442 for an example where the a chroot is used to install kernels - quite similar to your case.

Comment: @muru do I need the actual live CD for that, or can I use the GParted CD to run those commands?

Comment: A GParted live CD should do fine. I'd expect it to have everything needed.

Comment: @muru what about internet? I didn't bother setting it up.

Comment: Ah, that depends on how you connect to the internet. If you need some proprietary wifi driver, you might have difficulties on the GParted CD.

Comment: @muru so I need internet for finishing the install? IIRC, the download step had completed.

Comment: You may need it. If `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get install -f` do the job, you might not, but if you have to do `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, you will need it.

Comment: @muru I have a 64 bit system and GParted only comes in 32 bit, and I'm getting errors, I'll try with some other live CD.

Comment: @muru thanks so much!!! I'm able to boot up into a text-only ubunu 15 now! I guess I'll install KDE now.