# How recover from a bad update and no /sbin/init

Tags: boot, grub2

How do I get `/sbin/init` to install?

1. My boot started failing indicating no `/sbin/init` after an update.
2. Lots of playing around with `gparted`, `grub`, `supergrub2`...
3. So I created a bootable `gparted` disk.
4. Mounted my `/` and found it to be intact, `/sbin` is present but missing `/sbin/init`.
5. Stumbled on [No /sbin/init after upgrading to ubuntu 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714816/no-sbin-init-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-15).
6. Found [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels/28100#28100)
7. Went through the `mount`, `chroot` procedure outlined in restore procedure.
8. The procedure is for an upgrade to 15.04 from 14.04, but I want stay with 14.04, so I am using a reinstall. Its failing and I don't know where to go from here.
9. Aslo tried to reinstall `upstart` as per [Restoring /sbin/init from Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728178/restoring-sbin-init-from-live-cd), failed with a `dpkg` error processing `fontconfig` (see output below).

```
# apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-3.13.0.96-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.13.0.96-generic'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 98 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 532316 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic_3.13.0-96.143_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic (3.13.0-96.143) over (3.13.0-96.143) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_3.13.0.96.104_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (3.13.0.96.104) over (3.13.0.96.104) ...
Setting up fontconfig (2.11.1-0ubuntu6) ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic (3.13.0-96.143) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.13.0-96.143 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.13.0-96.143 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-86-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-86-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
Setting up linux-image-generic (3.13.0.96.104) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
# apt-get install --reinstall upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 98 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/399 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 532316 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../upstart_1.13.2-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking upstart (1.13.2-0ubuntu13) over (1.13.2-0ubuntu13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up fontconfig (2.11.1-0ubuntu6) ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up upstart (1.13.2-0ubuntu13) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@debian:/# ls -al /sbin/init
ls: cannot access /sbin/init: No such file or directory
```

- `/dev/sda3  /`
- `/dev/sda5  /home`
- `/dev/sda1  bios_grub`
- `/dev/sda2  swap`

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD30EZRX-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name      Flags
 1      17.4kB  1000MB  1000MB                  boot      bios_grub
 2      1000MB  13.0GB  12.0GB  linux-swap(v1)  swap
 4      513GB   713GB   200GB                   reserve1  msftdata
 5      713GB   1013GB  300GB   ext4            home      msftdata
 6      1013GB  1213GB  200GB                             msftdata
 3      1213GB  2000GB  787GB   ext4                      msftdata


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel? ignore
Model: PLDS DVD+-RW DH-16ABS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 279MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 2      1082MB  1095MB  12.8MB  primary               esp
```

Comment: Look at this question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/422264/how-to-debug-dpkg-configure-error-in-subprocess-post-installation) and look for error messages from dpkg.

Answer (score 4):

Never lose your hopes!

I've also faced a crash after apt-get install has installed some new packages... and at next reboot **BANG**! `/sbin/init: No such file or directory`. Also said `/etc/init: Permission denied`. Also said `/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off`.

Filesystem remained untouched at `/dev/vda1` and `fsck.ext4` returned: clean!

After a loooong research session, this worked for me: **+1 to hill** - a user from **launchpad**.

> 1. boot your droplet with a Recovery ISO - TigerShark
> 2. Network must be configured, either manually or via TigerShark script.
> 3. `mount -rw -o remount /dev/vda1 /mnt`
> 4. `chroot /mnt`
> 5. `unlink /etc/resolv.conf && echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`
> 6. `apt-get install init`
> 7. `update-initramfs -u`

After reboot your system. It will work fine. Enjoy!

**References**:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1652462
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: +1000! Thanks for all the research!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution? Full reinstall of your OS. Mark the packages you have installed and backup your /home and other related files/folders (unless you have /home on another partition (good for you!)), then reinstall, writing over the old broken OS partition.

Comment: yes, i do have a separate /home partition. I have a lot of "stuff" on this box, all sorts of tools, docker, vbox, ... How do do a full reinstall that does not kill all of my installs?  I'm two days into this, easy would be nice but, I'm willing to try complicated if it will work.

Comment: @TimR You should probably just go through and copy all of the personal files such as documents, pictures, etc. to a USB or external storage device. As for the installed packages such as tools, docker, etc. Just make a list of the names of the programs that you had installed and reinstall them after you reinstall the OS.

Comment: @OwenHines I understand I may have to do that, however its not my first choice. The disk didn't crash, I can mount it and it appears to be ok. If I have to go that route I'd like to learn something, like where does /sbin/init come from, what deletes it, and what installs it. Also, there are a couple of error msgs in the above captures having to do with dpkg and fontconfig. I do appreciate your taking the time to answer - thanks

Comment: @TimR I don't have an explanation for you, but I did want to say that you wanting to get something out of this for learning is a great mindset to have. Always apply that to problems. Keep it up!