# bash reboot : no such file or directory

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, reboot

I've been struggling with systemd and python issues (I wasn't able to update my computer). I have resolved theses issues but at the end, I couldn't run `reboot` command line. I've tried to recreate symlink but the `/sbin/reboot` folder seems to be empty...

I think it could be a  big problem.

Can I restart my computer safely while the `reboot` command is unknown? How can I fix this issue?

```bsh
****@*****:~$ reboot
bash: /sbin/reboot: No such file or directory
****@*****:~$ 
****@*****:~$ which reboot
****@*****:~$ 
****@*****:~$ sudo ln -f -s -- ../bin/systemctl /sbin/reboot
****@*****:~$ sudo ln -f -s -- ../bin/systemctl /sbin/shutdown
****@*****:~$ reboot
bash: /sbin/reboot: No such file or directory
****@*****:~$ which reboot
****@*****:~$
```

---

The commands that @nobody asks (sorry for delay) :

```
****@****:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
#
# initramfs.conf
# Configuration file for mkinitramfs(8). See initramfs.conf(5).
#
# Note that configuration options from this file can be overridden
# by config files in the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d directory.

#
# MODULES: [ most | netboot | dep | list ]
#
# most - Add most filesystem and all harddrive drivers.
#
# dep - Try and guess which modules to load.
#
# netboot - Add the base modules, network modules, but skip block devices.
#
# list - Only include modules from the 'additional modules' list
#

MODULES=most

#
# BUSYBOX: [ y | n | auto ]
#
# Use busybox shell and utilities.  If set to n, klibc utilities will be used.
# If set to auto (or unset), busybox will be used if installed and klibc will
# be used otherwise.
#

BUSYBOX=auto

#
# COMPCACHE_SIZE: [ "x K" | "x M" | "x G" | "x %" ]
#
# Amount of RAM to use for RAM-based compressed swap space.
#
# An empty value - compcache isn't used, or added to the initramfs at all.
# An integer and K (e.g. 65536 K) - use a number of kilobytes.
# An integer and M (e.g. 256 M) - use a number of megabytes.
# An integer and G (e.g. 1 G) - use a number of gigabytes.
# An integer and % (e.g. 50 %) - use a percentage of the amount of RAM.
#
# You can optionally install the compcache package to configure this setting
# via debconf and have userspace scripts to load and unload compcache.
#

COMPCACHE_SIZE=""

#
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz ]
#

COMPRESS=lz4

#
# NFS Section of the config.
#

#
# DEVICE: ...
#
# Specify a specific network interface, like eth0
# Overridden by optional ip= or BOOTIF= bootarg
#

DEVICE=

#
# NFSROOT: [ auto | HOST:MOUNT ]
#

NFSROOT=auto

#
# RUNSIZE: ...
#
# The size of the /run tmpfs mount point, like 256M or 10%
# Overridden by optional initramfs.runsize= bootarg
#

RUNSIZE=10%

****@****:~$


RUNSIZE=10%

****@****:~$ dpkg -l | grep lz4
ii  liblz4-1:amd64              1.9.2-2                           amd64        Fast LZ compression algorithm library - runtime
ii  lz4                         1.9.2-2                           amd64        Fast LZ compression algorithm library - tool

****@****:~$
```

Comment: Does `sudo shutdown -r now` do nothing? What sort of things have you been doing to your installation lately?

Comment: `/sbin/reboot folder seems to be empty` - /sbin/reboot shouldn't be a *folder* but an executable

Comment: Does `/bin/systemctl reboot` work?

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall systemd-sysv `  shows this any errors?

Comment: I fear if you manage to reboot, you system will not come up again. The error you show comes usually from mixing 32bit and 64bit binaries.

Comment: You re right Marco since the PC standby I had black screen
Since I couldnt boot again (sbin/init error)

Comment: So I ve followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/834053/how-recover-from-a-bad-update-and-no-sbin-init (1rst answer) but got 

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
W: Couldn't identify type of root file system for fsck hook
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-gi
 networkd-dispatcher
 python3-dbus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

at the end of `apt-get install init`

Comment: But boot successfully !!!! But still with the `init ramfs decoding failed`

Comment: `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and `dpkg -l | grep lz4` please.

Comment: `reboot` is in `/usr/sbin`, at least on my system. It's a symlink to `bin systemctl`. Is `/usr/sbin` in your PATH? Please add output of `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: @Yves might want to have put this into your post as an edit.  And indicate you got the information from the commands asked for in comments.

Comment: @ThomasWard right good idea thanks

Comment: @mook765 I fixed the reboot path, my issue is now to update my Ubuntu. I succeed to update but not to upgrade. I have the following error : `Errors encountered during execution: python3 python3-gi networkd-dispatcher python3-dbus E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`