# Stuck when updating lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, 14.10, bootloader, usb-installation

Strange feeling that is should be so difficult to update lubuntu to a newer version.

I'm running lubuntu 14.10 on an old computer. I was planning to update it to 17.10 but failed. 
First, I tried to use "Sofware Updater" - but 15.04 was not available.

Then I tried to make a bootable cd (not DVD) but it was not possible due to space limitation.

Then I tried to make a bootable USB by using "startup disk creator", but boot loader failed to install so bios didn't recognice the USB as a boot disk.
I then tried using the dd command but bios didn't recognice that USB either.

I've used 4 hours on this. If it wasen't for the weekend I would never had time to do it. So, I'm wondering; should it really be that difficult to update to a newer version?

Anyone who knows a quick fix?

Comment: The "official" method for upgrading Ubuntu is from version-to-version (non-LTS), or from LTS-to-LTS. Upgrading from Lubuntu 14.10 to 17.10 would seem to be asking for problems. I'd recommend an install of 15.04, then progress up to 17.10. Or, a fresh install of 17.10. In both cases, be sure to backup your personal files first.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm basically trying to do a fresh install of 17.10

Comment: I think it is easier and safer to install **mkusb** and clone from the iso file to the USB pendrive; mkusb wraps a safety belt around `dd`.  See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb. In Lubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions, there is a new version of the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator, which is also a cloning tool, and it is also very reliable (to create USB boot drives of Ubuntu and the Ubuntu community flavours (Lubuntu et al)). If you have a very old computer, you need a 32-bit (alias i386) version of Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` ? I'd start with that.
Since you have an "old computer", you should probably stick to 16.04 LTS (available here : [official Lubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu/LTS))

You might find some answers here, too : [How to Upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588019/how-to-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04/588022)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But unfortunatly it didn't help.
This is how the terminal looked like:

Comment: administrator@ASE-Vostro-200:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade [sudo] password for administrator: Checking for a new Ubuntu release Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore. For upgrade information, please visit: http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife Feil [translation:error] Upgrade tool signature
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Feil [translation:error] Upgrade tool
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Hentet [translation:get] 0 B på 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'vivid.tar.gz.gpg' missing Failed to fetch Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
Okay I found a solution which finally worked; 
I formatted the USB drive as "Hidden HPFS/NTFS (Bootable)" and run the dd command. That finally made it.