# How do I check for release updates that are not beta but might not be LTS?

Tags: upgrade, lts, do-release-upgrade, beta

I have a cron job that checks for new releases.   I want to make sure it emails me when a new release is out of beta and ready to install.    I want to upgrade to both long term support (LTS) releases and non-LTS releases.  Is there a command that will tell me that such a release is available?

I've tried using `do-release-upgrade -c -q` and it tells me about the new release *unless* I'm currently on LTS and the next release is *not* LTS, ([as documented here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)).

I've tried using `do-release-upgrade -d -c -q`.  It tells me about non-LTS releases, but it also tells me about beta releases.   For example, if I use it right now it tells me that `15.04` is available, but it hasn't actually been fully released yet, ([as documented here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)).

What is the command to tell me about **all** releases that have been fully released, whether or not they are LTS?

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging around in the code for `do-release-upgrade`.  It appears that it downloads a file from http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/ to check for new releases.  It downloads different files from there depending on the command line options provided.  The file that would suit my needs is http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

I don't see any options that will make do-release-upgrade download exactly that file, however it's easy enough to do with some command line tools:

```
currentrelease=`lsb_release -r | grep -oE '[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}'`
availablerelease=`curl -s http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release | grep Version | tail -n 1 | grep -oE '[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}'`
if [ "$currentrelease" != "$availablerelease" ]
then
    echo "New release '$availablerelease' available. To upgrade use:"
    echo "  sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive"
fi
```