# How can I get an Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) Beta1 installer (if I'm ready to test it)?

Tags: system-installation, cd-image, beta, 15.10

Although Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) Beta1 has been [announced](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/Beta1/ReleaseAnnouncement), I can't see a stand-alone image that I can try to install.

(I'm in particular interested in using [the installation image to change my system from 32bit to 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/a/361763/19753); therefore just [running `update-manager -d`](https://askubuntu.com/a/12910/19753) from an already installed system is not suitable for me.)

Comment: @muru Thanks for the useful link to [a more recent question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one) regarding the switch from 32bit OS to 64bit OS. (I only have read [the older Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/a/361763/19753).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer which said (but got removed) that one can use an application called "TestDrive" to get and test the daily beta images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the current install iso files -> http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Concerning the upgrade of 32 bit system to 64 bit : It's not recommended, make a new install.

Comment: But it's possible 32->64 =)

Comment: @A.B. I know, and for those who don't have enough trouble in their life already, it is a pretty good chance to get some delicious improvement on that ! =)