# How can I upgrade from current release to next daily build? (15.10 > 16.04 daily)

Tags: upgrade, daily-build

I tried, for development purposes, to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 with this command:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

It didn't upgrade. What's the correct way?

Comment: Related: [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```