# Will there be bad effect if I do a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10 without removing my old home folder

Tags: system-installation, configuration, 18.10

Will the old config file affect Ubuntu 18.10 in the bad way?
Such as the themes, etc.

Comment: Possibly significant is knowing how old your config/home folder is, but in my experience no.  GNOME will for the most part ignore themes etc. that it cannot use (they'll be exceptions because not all themes will fully follow rules, but these won't be default installed themes).  You will not, or should not have any bad effects (this is mostly based on my prior experience with many upgrades over the years)

Comment: @guiverc But 18.10 change the themes, I'm on 18.04.

Comment: The OS doesn't allow me to upgrade to 18.10, so a clean install is the only way to go.

Comment: Yes you can upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 18.10.  This [18.10] box used to be 18.04 LTS, but the default path of upgrade for LTS releases is to the next LTS release.  Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1 but if you go into "Software & Updates" you will have a check box "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: " which for LTS is marked "Long Term Support versions" which needs to be changed to "For any new version".  You're welcome to use a re-install, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @guiverc I had tried it before, and it refused to upgrade.

Comment: @TomBrossman No, I'm not afraid of losing data in home folder, because I know it won't, the problem I concern is that the old config file may causes bad effect on 18.10.

Comment: It seems like I need to remove all the unofficial softwares to upgrade.

Comment: I need to remove the mesa-git.

Comment: Yes to upgrade all non-official repos should be removed (including all PPAs, though most will be disabled in process if not removed) as the upgrade process is tested using only official Ubuntu & Canonical repos (main, universe, multiverse, restricted). It seems like you've heavily added-to or modified your system so a re-install will possibly be easier unless you left good breadcrumbs (documentation) showing what you did so you can reverse it, perform upgrade, then re-apply (adjusting if necessary - many changes made usually are to add later features thus won't be necessary in later releases).