# Cant upgrade frome 21.10 to 22.04 due to lost time

Tags: 22.04

So i lost my chance to a normal upgrade at april and lost my chance to upgrade to 22.04 as well.
Now i cant upgrade at all.
What are my options?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo do-release-upgrade` It's only a few days off, I'm not sure it makes a difference.

Comment: It gives me 404 on the upgrades

Comment: The premise of the question is false. Normal (non `-d`) release-upgrades from 21.10 to 22.04 *have not begun yet*. They will start in early August, same as LTS-to-LTS release-upgrades, when 22.04.1 becomes available.

Comment: Ok, so y the 404 when trying to upgrade? And what do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited.

Your best option may be now just to reinstall the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04LTS [without losing data in the Home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder) as outlined in this old but still relevant Q&A.

But, please do ensure that you have first backed up any essential data you wish to retain before progressing further no matter which option you choose.

Comment: Ok read it. Its very old... Do you think i can just install the 22.04? ,From iso? Is there a way to upgrade from the iso?

Comment: "Is there a way to upgrade from the iso?" not that I can think of. Your best option is to install 22.04 LTS from scratch but note the caveats about backups before doing anything if you have important data to retain.

Comment: My only important data is my plex DB... Thats huge work restoring plex. I feel so stupid

Answer (score 0):

On Kubuntu I was able to get the upgrade to run by going into Software Sources (Discover -> Settings -> Software Sources) and changing the download mirror to "main server" from what it had been. Then I opened a terminal and ran `apt upgrade` and then `pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE`.

Comment: Why `pkexec` and not `sudo`? Is any GUI involved with it?

Comment: That is copied from the official upgrade guide here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades/Kubuntu. They also have a terminal-only option which uses `sudo`. I just prefer the partial-GUI option.