# Upgrade Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04

Tags: 23.10, 24.04

tried

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

---

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

Comment: 24.04 isn't released yet.

Comment: @ArturMeinild what about Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) Daily Build that is available

Comment: Daily Build = Not released.

Comment: @AlokKumar 24.04 **is not released yet**.  The Daily Build is designed for people who want to test the next version of Ubuntu during its development.  24.04 has a [release schedule](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649) that has its timeline for release being in late April.  Until that happens and it is announced officially as "released", you will not see it in `do-release-upgrade` nor will it be supported on this site until it is released.

Comment: Read `man do-release-upgrade` and serach for `--devel-release` option, ie. you want to go to the *development* release which is what it is for. You can also use the `-d` as a shorter option, OR follow the documented upgrade procedures which list it too.

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: I wrote an answer on this only recently (*on a rather similar question*)... I also close-voted that question (*thus that question may have been deleted*) as the *development* release is off-topic until it's released..   As in that answer; the `--devel-release` or `-d` action causes the normal *released* meta file (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release) to **not** be used; insteading using the *development* version (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development) to be used instead where *noble* can be found...   Exactly as its documented

Comment: FYI: I note you mention *daily* in a comment; refer to https://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ for probably the best place to find what *daily* ISOs are available; ie the ISO Quality Assurance tracker. It lists all dailes & points to where they can be downloaded at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ (*which includes non-released ISOs too*) including for re-spins (ie. what will be 22.04.5 etc for already release products). I suggest using a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site for help though with *unreleased* or *QA intended* products.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct. 23.10 is the most recent release of Ubuntu. There is no newer release yet.

About 48 days from today, Ubuntu 24.04 is planned to be released. It is NOT released yet. Until then, it is in development.

24.04 = yy.mm
yy = 24 (2024)
mm = 04 (April)

Comment: what about Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) Daily Build that is available

Comment: It's the daily snapshot of current development that will become 24.04 upon release. It is intended for testing. Development and testing of software takes place in the open, of course. We want more testers! Please do test it, and report the problems you discover to the bug tracker.

Comment: Reminder: AskUbuntu is **not** a venue to discuss testing or pre-release development. AskUbuntu is for support **after** release.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: @ArturMeinild Sorry, I didn't know that, so I ended up with a couple of development 24.04 machines. Sarcasm off: it just work, see `man do-release-upgrade` about `-d` switch.