# Does upgrading alter partitions?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, 11.04

I was wondering if it's safe to upgrade Maverick Meerkat to Natty (I believe I'm fully aware of the bugginess of Natty at the moment). The only thing that's of concern is altering of other partitions during the install.

Will it wipe any partitions out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, upgrading to Natty will not alter any partitioning, provided you use the correct method:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Also see `man do-release-upgrade`

I feel obligated to link to [How safe it is to upgrade to natty at the moment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14896/how-safe-it-is-to-upgrade-to-natty-at-the-moment) :-)

Answer (score 1):

if i were you, i wouldn't install natty in a computer which has important data in that partitons. bear in mind that it's not finished and could screw 'em up. it shouldn't alter them, but don't rely on something that unstable.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, Alex. I've backed everything up on my other PC and ready to go on bug patrol.

Comment: That's what we like to see. :-D

Comment: you're welcome. nice hunting!

Answer (score 1):

No upgrading to Natty will not change your partitions. However it may well install a new copy of the GRUB bootloader.

Earlier in Natty's development this almost prevented me from accessing my other partitions - the other operating systems didn't show up on the startup list (although the data was actually all safe).

So as long as you're fairly confident with Ubuntu and [know where to find help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) if things go wrong then go for it.