# Natty Alpha Testing "Kept Back" Updates, Ubuntu or My System?

Tags: 11.04, updates, testing

I'm testing Natty and theres a hefty list of updates that are "kept back"

now to the question

are these packages that are most likely held back due to Ubuntu (and will be made available once dependencies and whatnot are added/updated.)

**OR**

is there a chance that I screwed my system in a way that some updates aren't compatible

Comment: Take a look at [There's an issue with an Alpha Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: well the question is whether it is an issue at all. I thought i'd ask users first before i troubled the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Depending on the state of the archive at the time it could remove packages and result in things breaking.

Comment: thanks, dist-upgrade doesn't keep back packages. and thanks jorge as well.