# How to install 3d support?

Tags: video, 11.04, 3d, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I'm trying Natty and after an upgrade I received this message:

"Sorry, you don't have 3d support, install it for your graphic hardware to get Unity or please reboot and select 'Classic session' at startup."

So I want to install 3D support but I don't know how to. My machine is a Sony Vaio VGN-SR29XN Laptop with Intel Graphics, but I would like to know the general instructions.

P.S. : I've no problem with the CLI, I just don't know how to proceed in this particular case (what driver, or program...).

Comment: What kind of intel graphics do you have? Normally intel graphics are supported out the box. Chances are you have a broken upgrade it is just a matter of applying some more updates to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. By googling I found that the Intel graphics chip on my laptop is GMA 4500mhd, but I dont know haw to confirm it.

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel and I got: xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version. Anyway I still don't have 3D support. Is this the wrong driver? There's a long list of xserver-xorg-video-... drivers in apt-get.

Comment: It should be the correct driver as far as I know, I'm not sure if your card is black listed or something, but chances are that an upgrade to X was incompatible with your driver. P.S. you really should be using 10.10 until 11.04 is stable.

Comment: You can confirm your graphics by installing hardinfo and going to the graphics/display section - you could also add a screenshot here.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do