# Why are the close, maximize, minimize buttons in opposite order when you have the window maximized?

Tags: 11.04

where is the consistency.. I don't know how many times I have hit the maximize button instead of the close button... this makes no sense what so ever

Comment: [There's an issue with an Alpha Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)