# What is the reason application menus in the top bar are hidden by default?

Tags: 11.04, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Unity hide the menubar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22486/why-does-unity-hide-the-menubar)

Why are the application-specific menus in the top bar of unity hidden by default, and showing up when you hover over them?

It seems to me that it would make more sense to display them always, so that's why I'd like to know what rationale there is for this?

Answer (score 3):

Your question will be answered after you read [this document](https://docs.google.com/View?id=dfkkjjcj_1776g5ztgbc3). It is the basis of the design we are currently using. Thing is... this is all design so one person will see this as an excellent way of dealing with it and others strongly disagree.

For instance... Matthew Paul Thomas made a comment on the [ayatana mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/msg05037.html) with some good arguments why it should not be this way.

Discussions about design tend to be long and someone just decided to go with this. Unity still needs to grow and it could be that this does not work as good as intended. If so 11.10 will have it in another fashion. Who knows :)