# Why is my display name in Ubuntu Software Center some weird set of letters?

Tags: 11.04, software-center, single-sign-on, reviews

In USC, after I submit a review, my display name is "Bnxdcty"... a swell name, but where did it come from?

I have checked the ubuntu single sign on page, verified my nickname on there, changed it to something else and back again for good measure, but still my reviewer name is somehow still "Bnxdcty". I even unauthorized ubuntu software center and then re-opened it/authorized it to my account.

Does this just appear as this to me and others see my correct user nickname, because it seems most other people have their Ubuntu Single Sign On nickname correctly displayed?

It doesn't bother as much as it confuses me.

I just know it will be something stupid in my account settings that everyone knows but me.

Comment: See [There's an issue with an Alpha Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Also: [When are questions about “ubuntu+1” appropriate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)

Comment: well i read that and i feel it's a bit offensive to assume i don't take such things into consideration. This question isn't about an assumption that there is a bug or something wrong. Ubuntu single sign on is an established thing and if it's something that is just a setting to change on my account then it's not a bug and it's not solely related to natty. It may be, but i'm not bug reporting. it's a question for users in case somebody knows. what other point does this website have than to foster such questions? Why bother Natty devs if it's a simple account problem.

Comment: At this point in the cycle it's best to just report this as a bug, USC has a server side piece as well so who knows what kind of interaction there is with the SSO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing on 11.04. When reviewing an application it tells me my name is "Greg Auger" (which it is) but once the review is posted it shows up as belonging to "fluteflute".

I suggest you go to [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/) and [sign in](https://launchpad.net/+login) using your Ubuntu Single Sign On details. If you clixk on your name in the top right corner of the pageyou will go to your userpage. From here click "Change Details". I'd be interested to know what yours says, mine is below:

[image: Launchpad]

Comment: hey thanks, mine shows my name as ikeahloe and my display name as ike. i really have no idea where "Bnxdcty" came from haha. this appears to probably be a bug, so i'll mark this as answered. i'll leave it here though in case someone with the answer stumbles by.