# To fix 'Grub rescue' problem

Tags: grub2

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 in my Laptop.After installing Ubuntu 11.10 along side with them and restarting the system only  'files not found' ; 'Grub rescue' appears on the screen.How could I fix the problem?

Comment: Did you take a look at this question? - [Stuck on Grub command line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32135/stuck-on-grub-command-line/32250#32250)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a live CD to recover your Grub installation.

Follow the steps in desgua's answer [Stuck on Grub command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32135/stuck-on-grub-command-line/32250#32250) as well as having a good read through the [Ubuntu Community documentation page for Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).