# GRUB broken again

Tags: grub2, mbr

Please help, my grub is broken again, and again, I don't know why, maybe latest update, I'm not sure, it starts to annoy me.

Error I get when I boot:

```
Symbol not found: grub_divmod64_fulll
```

And it prompts grub rescue console:

```
grub rescue>
```

I tried to follow this [tut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32135/stuck-on-grub-command-line/32250#32250), after booting from live DC I did:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 163.9 GB, 163927522816 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19929 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 640.1 GB, 640133946880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3dcf5202

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        3917    31463271    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2            3918       77826   593667163    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5            3918       43080   314576766    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb6           77328       77826     4000768   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb7           43081       77197   274041856   83  Linux
/dev/sdb8           77197       77327     1045504   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -Th 
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs          aufs    1.5G  101M  1.4G   7% /
none      devtmpfs    1.5G  700K  1.5G   1% /dev
/dev/sr0   iso9660    686M  686M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0
          squashfs    658M  658M     0 100% /rofs
none         tmpfs    1.5G  216K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.5G  628K  1.5G   1% /tmp
none         tmpfs    1.5G   96K  1.5G   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs    1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /var/lock
/dev/sdb1  fuseblk     31G   12G   19G  38% /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
mount: mount point /mnt/dev/pts does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys 
mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt 
chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub 
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot stat `aufs'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: That bit about 'not containing a valid partition' table doesn't sound particularly good, I'm afraid. You wouldn't be in a RAID configuration by any chance?

Comment: No. I don't know what RAID is actually. I had a normal dual boot, window has it's own hdd, and Ubuntu it's own. Only strange thing is that system shutdown failed yesterday with some trace dumps and I forced shutdown. Today I got posted error. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have a 163 GB drive that is not being used.  You also skipped a step in the instructions you were following to mount the hard disk in /mnt before the bind mounts.  In your case it seems /dev/sda isn't being used, so you will want to mount /dev/sdb instead, and install grub there.

Comment: @psusi But it says that `/dev/sdb1  fuseblk     31G   12G   19G  38% /mnt` which means it is already mounted, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: If I boot live CD, and do `sudo grub-update` will that upgrade actual grub or just virtual one since it is live CD? Also, in live CD mode, I see grub is not installed, but grub-pc.

Comment: I'll probably give rescuetux a shot http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/

Comment: You need to follow the instructions.  If you boot from a livecd, it won't be mounted until you mount it as the instructions say.  Then you need to `chroot` so when you run `update-grub`, you are running the one on the hd instead of the cd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it with [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

I still have:

```
umpirsky@umpirsky:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640133946880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250261615 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3dcf5202

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    62926604    31463271    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        62926666  1250260991   593667163    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        62926668   692080199   314576766    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6      1242259456  1250260991     4000768   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       692080640  1240164351   274041856   83  Linux
/dev/sda8      1240166400  1242257407     1045504   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 163.9 GB, 163927522816 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19929 cylinders, total 320170943 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

But everything works like before.