# Can't boot after installing Ubuntu into separate partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

When I try to boot my computer, I just get a command prompt:

"no such partition
grub>_"

I partitioned my computer hard disk into two partitions:

-- First partition (C:) has the already installed Windows XP (marked as primary partition)
-- Second partition (K:): I installed Ubuntu 11.10 into this one (marked as logical partition, with the name "sd5 or something like that).

After installing Ubuntu, I could boot only Windows.

Did a google search to see what to do. Based on that: an OS to boot, it has to be in a primary partition, and that logical partition can be changed into a primary partition.

Used "MiniTool Partitioning Home Edition 7.8:
-- Changed second partition with Ubuntu into primary partition
-- But, did not change the first already primary into logical partition.
So now, I had two primary partitions.

Now, neither OS boots. Only get the command prompt I noted at the beginning of this post
Right now, I can boot only from a USB-bootable Ubuntu..

Please help!. Thanks for all help.

Comment: I suppose that the best options for you are install the Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin (Long time supported version-LTS) and uses the Boot-repair from USB stick. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot into the USB Ubuntu without a problem, I'd open terminal and attempt the following:

```
sudo update grub
```

This will solve the problem if it's simple.

Also - not sure on this, but I think Ubuntu needs to be run from a Primary partition.
If possible, re-install Ubuntu as a primary partition.

I recognize that command line, it's the GRUB command line.

This may help then:  [Stuck on GRUB Command Line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32135/stuck-on-grub-command-line)