# Ubuntu 11.04 - No Unity in Live-Mode using a Nvidia GraphicsCard

Tags: unity, 11.04, nvidia

Id like to install Ubuntu 11.04 on my desktop computer. 
I heard that there are still problems using unity with nvidia graphics cards.

In my case I have got a Nvidia GTX 460.
I tried a live image and there was no working unity.
I got nautilus, windows 2000-theme. No Compiz.

Should I probably first install ? Perhaps than unitys working fine ?

Comment: 11.04 is currently Alpha so things might not work right. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate for better instructions on how to proceed.

Comment: It works, but yes. Only after installing ubuntu 11.04.
Then I activated the nvidia graphics-driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a live USB with storage enabled then you can safely download the nvidia-current package from the software-center (do a full search of the package). Restart after it is installed and you will have Unity.