# How do I set a theme in Oneiric?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk, appearance, 11.10

I'm using Oneiric, and have some default theme set. I understand Unity is using Gtk3, and that the usual Ubuntu themes haven't been ported.

- How do I set the theme in Oneiric?
- Where is/will the new Appearance settings dialog /be?

Comment: No, Unity is yet to use GTK3,it uses GTK2 hence the theme is broken the default theme is called raleigh, and you would need a GTK3 to be able to apply it as that is what Ubuntu is going to use.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: So, once this is rectified, will it reappear? I'm looking at Alpha 3, and getting worried that this is going to be what we're rolling with.

Comment: @CraigM: Me too. It's also appalling that central Ubuntu contributors have closed this question to prevent Ubuntu being criticized.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Well, I'm not so worried about the question being criticized, as much as I'd like the assurance that it'll be fixed at some point. That's all.

Comment: As a "future visitor" this question could have helped me, if it were allowed to be updated. It appears there is still no way to change any theme settings in Oneiric, one day before final freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the gnome-tweak-tool to change your GTK3 theme.

Download from https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3/+sourcepub/1775469/+listing-archive-extra

Comment: After the release, this is the only way to do it. No decent settings dialog was shipped in the final release.

Comment: If you don't want to pull all those dependencies you can do the sam e with Ubuntu Tweak.

Comment: Right, the new Ubuntu tweak has these settings

Answer (score 0):

Currently:

- Window border:

  You have to set the window border theme using `gconf-editor` at the path:

  ```
  /apps/metacity/general/theme
  ```
- GTK/Icon/Cursor theme:

  Can be set using `dconf-editor` from the `dconf-tools` package at the paths:

  ```
  org.gnome.desktop.interface.gtk-theme
  org.gnome.desktop.interface.icon-theme
  org.gnome.desktop.interface.cursor-theme
  ```

AFAIK there are currently two ports of Ambiance in the works (make sure you have the `gtk3-engines-unico` package installed):

1. One from Luca Forina (Lucazade) at https://code.launchpad.net/~lucazade/+junk/ambiance-gtk3. Follow the instructions to get the branch, then copy the `gtk-3.0` folder to `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance` and set the GTK theme to Ambiance.
2. A second one from Andrea Cimitan (Cimi) which has been merged to the `light-themes` package - so it's probably the official one. You can find the code [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-art-pkg/light-themes/trunk). Again, just download like instructed and move the theme files to `/usr/share/themes` (move/backup the old ones first).