# what is the shortcut to force a logout?

Tags: shortcuts, logout

I am using the alpha 2 version of 11.10 and the keyboard options there do not have an option to force a logout.

Can you tell me the keyboard shortcut so i can add it myself?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: But isn't that topic about bugs? It's possible that the change to gnome 3 changed the shortcut used to kill the xserver or that i have just missed the menu that lets me choose one. Either way, the command that is executed after one presses control-alt-backspace on the current version of Ubuntu should probably work on the next one as well. That's why my question is neither about a bug, nor about an alpha release only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the latest update added an "options" menu on the keyboard preferences-->layouts that lets me activate the "control-alt-delete" shortcut like before. Or it might have always been there and i missed it.

Answer (score 11):

When I have this problem, I simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> into a terminal, log in, and type

```
killall -u  [username] gnome-session
```

This will basically kill all of your processes and log you out. If you want to logout all users at the same time in this manner, then you leave out the `-u [username]` part.

I guess you could create a new keyboard shortcut that runs this command. The only problem with this that I can forsee is if the freeze-up is because of gnome itself. Then it may not recognize the shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Log-in

Then run this command on Terminal: `killall -u USERNAME`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can open Keyboard shortcuts and create a new shortcut. Run the command `killall -u yourusername gnome-session`.

Comment: That was what i was looking for until an hour ago that i found out that the shortcut is still there - thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> in the keyboard options this kills the x server and will probably work even if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> does not.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised that no one mentioned `sudo service lightdm restart`

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is the same as 11.04 (or possibly it's just that I'm running Gnome 3), but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> brings up a box allowing me to logout.

Comment: True, but if everything is stuck there is no way for that box to appear.