# Third mouse-button emulation

Tags: xorg, 11.10, udev

Up until version 11.04 of ubuntu I could simply add an option to my X InputClass to emulate a third mouse button for my HP TrackPoint like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Trackpoint"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "True"
EndSection
```

I recently updated to the 11.10 to test the new features and I am satisfied so far but the before mentioned method stopped working. I suppose it's related to the x-server update.
I also tried adding a udev rule like this:

```
ENV{x11_options.Emulate3Buttons}="True"
```

which is also ignored.

Is there anything I missed or something important that has changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There's an issue with an Alpha Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: 11.10 Is an Alpha release. You need to report this as a bug if it's not work as expected.

Comment: I wasn't sure this is a bug. It might just have been another change in the system architecture. Well then. I'm going to report this and see what happens.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be fixed to me -- it is ignoring my Emulate3Button setting in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-marblemouse.conf that was working fine under 11.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug seems to be fixed now. Without me reporting it.

In 12.04 and 12.10 the settings can be found with dconf-editor or dconf in `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/middle-button-enabled` and persist over standby and reboot.

Comment: so, no udev-hacking is needed anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Middle mouse button emulation can be enabled in Ubuntu 11.10 via a little program called gpointing-device-settings:

```
sudo aptitude install gpointing-device-settings
```

(see https://grepmonster.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/ubuntu-11-10-middle-mouse-button-emulation/)

Comment: The problem with this is that the setting is only remembered until a suspend or a reboot occurs. The bug report I created for this is ignored like everything else concerning gpointing-device-settings https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=gpointing-device-settings

Answer (score 2):

The third mouse button can be enabled system wide by adding a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-3rdbutton.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "middle button"
   MatchIsPointer "on"
   MatchDriver "libinput"
   Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
EndSection
```

I use this on my HP nc2400 with Fedora 23, and it works.

The source of this information is the corrected and adapted config of [comment 14 of Red Hat’s bug 1227992](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1227992#c14).

Comment: I don't have Gnome and this worked for me!