# How to use both mouse buttons simultaneously as middle-click?

Tags: mouse, input-devices, button, remapping, mouse-wheel

The wheel-button on my mouse appears to be malfunctioning, but the mouse itself, including the wheel, is still fine.

Is there any possibility to assign the "middle-click"-function to something like both traditional buttons being pressed at the same time?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/53856/third-mouse-button-emulation

Comment: Yes, thank you. I actually just found a solution myself in the official Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#A2-button_Mice (Typical case of search before you ask..) Well, since the bounty on this question is gone now, I'll just wait for a lucky responder. ;)

Comment: While the linked question mentioned one of known solutions, this question isn't a duplicate of that. For a generic question that could cover all releases and flavours of Ubuntu, I'd rather upvote this +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears a bug existed but was fixed. Check this [duplicate issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53856/third-mouse-button-emulation).

You can also use the resource posted in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#A2-button_Mice).

***TL;DR***

> If you have a 2-button mouse and need middle-mouse emulation, here are the steps to follow to request adding a quirk for your hardware:
>
> 1. Create a file named /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/middle-mouse-button.conf with the following contents:

```
     Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "middle button emulation class"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
     EndSection
```

> 2. If you use GNOME 3 or Unity, an additional step is needed. Execute the following command

```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse middle-button-enabled true
```

> Otherwise, GNOME 3's settings will override X's.
>
> 3. Restart X, and verify this works.
> 4. File a bug with the title "Quirk for 2-button mouse ", like this:

```
     ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

> 5. Attach to the bug report the output of 'sudo lsinput' and 'sudo dmidecode'