# screen lock ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, login-screen

While in ubuntu 11.04 I could disable the lock in screen after suspend this option doesn't exist anymore in 11.10. at least in gconfgeditor the option is not available anymore

As I dont want to fight to reopen the issue, I just edit the question to include the solution I found:

Install dconf editor as part of the dconf tools and start the editor via the dash.

Then navigate to org.gnome.desktop.lockdown and voila

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Alpha/Beta questions are offtopic here, since "Ubuntu+1" changes so rapidly answers aren't really useful for long term reference. [Here are some tips](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) on how to proceed.

Comment: hey why is this question closed? I have the same question, how to disable login/password prompt after resuming from suspension on 11.10 ?