# Gnome-Panel missing

Tags: gnome, panel

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I removed the new mac look to make ubuntu look like classic ubuntu of previous versions. After that only desktop is there. Rest everything is missing including panels. But from login menu in GDM I can choose Classic ubuntu and login to get all details. Otherwise in normal Ubuntu login it is not possible. How can I get back that panel.

Even Alt+f2 not working

Comment: Hit Alt+ F2 and type `gnome-panel` See if that works

Comment: Please see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: off topic: @ Akhil How does Unity looks even remotely to OSX?

Comment: @Uri He probably just doesn't want the launcher (which he's probably comparing to OS X's dock) and the global menu.

Comment: Hope to know what have you removed instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the old Windows 95-look (to use your kind of language), then you should consider switching to Xfce, or at least xfce4-panel, which is similar to gnome-panel. It even supports gnome-panel applets.  Gnome2 as you've been used to, is deprecated and not developed anymore. I don't think it's even possible to run it properly with 11.10. Xfce is actively developed though, and is a very suitable replacement for the more conservative.

There is something called gnome-panel 3, but that's completely different.