# Terrible Gnome Shell appearance

Tags: themes, gnome

I am using Gnome 3 with Ubuntu 11.04 but I have a strange problem that happened after some updates. I can change the Gnome GTK theme but I am not able to change the Gnome Shell theme and my titlebar is at least annoying.

If I change theme it just changes the title background color from blue to orange etc.

In addition in Shell Theme it does not allowing me to choose a theme. It says something about extensions but if I choose "Shell extensions" that displays an empty page withnno configuration.

[image]

Comment: please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the user theme extension, alternate status bar extension and alternate tab etension from the gnome 3 tab in the ubuntu software center then hit alt+f2 press r then hit enter if you dont have that then just search for how to install those and you should get your answer