# Touchpad disabled after login on a  Lenovo G550 laptop

Tags: login, touchpad

I installed touchpad-indicator to manage my touchpad settings while using an external USB mouse. Now, after some-time, my touchpad has stopped working after login to the Ubuntu system. It works fine till the login screen, then stops. I have tried removing and re-installing the touchpad-indicator application, but it doesn't help.

Can anyone please tell me the steps i need in order to evoke my touchpad again. I am using 
Ubuntu 11.10 with Kernel version 3.0.0.9 on a Lenovo G550 laptop.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.  11.10 is still in alpha - as such this is probably a bug.  Details as to how to progress such problems are discussed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: My touchpad is not working in Ubuntu 11.10, but it was in 11.04. The red nub on my Lenovo W520 is working fine. The fix posted does not work for me. Update: There is a nice thread on the issue here: http://bit.ly/qx2da3. Bug reports are linked on the 4th page.

Comment: I have the same problem. After login, the mouse touchpad of my HP laptop dv6385ea (2007) stops working. However if I login as a Guest, it works flawlessly! None of the above tweaks worked for me. Help please.

Comment: Same issue on my T520. No trackpad but nub works. Running this command fixes it - synclient TouchpadOff=0
Thanks Daniel for the link.

Comment: Disabling the 'disable touchpad while typing' option fixed it for me. Sounds like a similar fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

in the terminal worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518293

Comment: I have tried the solution, but it doesn't work. the prob. is there b'fore i upgraded to oneric. I had touchpad-indicator installed, and have tried removing it as well, but it does not help.

Comment: The problem persists before I upgraded to Oneric. I had Touchpad-indicator installed. Can it be an issue with a kernel upgrade ?