# How can I get back Super+a/Super+f?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, 11.10

My prefered way to launch programms in Natty was to hit Super+a and type a few letters. This does not work in Oneiric anymore. I have to use the mouse which is really cumbersome.

Alt+F2 is not a good replacement. Is it possible to activate the Super+a shortcut or will it be back until Oneiric release?

Comment: Please see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: This is a bug in the beta: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/834078

Answer (score 2):

Check out GNOME Do. http://do.davebsd.com/

I use it all the time and I love it!

Comment: In dont want gnome do. I use the application lens in Natty all the time and I love it. But Canonical broke my heart

Comment: @burli: Do you need counselling? It's free (after the cover charge). *~The Unicorns.*