# How to report a bug for no sound through headphones?

Tags: bug-reporting

So this is the first version of Ubuntu that stops the sound from coming out of my speakers when I plug in headphones. Unfortunately it also stops the sound altogether... I would like to submit a bug report but I can't remember how, nor what program I should submit it for?

Comment: I have the same problem and the bug is reported in here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-utils/+bug/868915

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) should have all the information you need about issues with alpha and beta releases.

In particular, [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) covers how to report bugs.

As for what package you should file the bug report under, try to narrow it down as much as possible. If it only happens for specific programs, there's probably a common link between them. If all of your system audio is broken, I would file it under [ALSA.](https://launchpad.net/alsa)

Comment: The asker would probably still like to know what package their bug will need to be filed against.

Comment: Good point. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The bug should be filed against [`alsa-driver` in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver) (e.g., with `ubuntu-bug linux-sound-base`), *not* against [the project ALSA](https://launchpad.net/alsa) or [the project ALSA driver](https://launchpad.net/alsa-driver). (Bugs are categorized against source packages like `alsa-driver`, but `ubuntu-bug` takes binary packages as arguments, so it's necessary to report it against one of `alsa-driver`'s associated binary packages, of which [`linux-sound-base`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/linux-sound-base) usually makes the most sense.)

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround (for a Dell notebook):

Add the following line to **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

`options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-dmic`

'dell-m6-dmic' might be replaced with 'dell-m6' or 'dell-eq'