# How do I get rid of double battery monitor status?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two battery indicator symbols, how do I get rid of one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65803/two-battery-indicator-symbols-how-do-i-get-rid-of-one)

It seems there is a bug that displays an extra battery monitor in Oneiric. From what I found, it is not right in the panel, but in the wallpaper. Please the following images:

[image: Extra battery monitor in panel in Oneiric]

[image: Extra battery monitor in panel and expo in Oneiric]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Remember that Oneiric is in Beta, so please see this question for more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: Please reopen this as it seems to still be a problem (for me as well) and I have not noticed anything similar mentioned by others, so we must have something in common others don't have (not sure if to report a bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is not a battery indicator in the wallpaper. When you go into expo mode, any old notification-area icons show up on top of the wallpaper. You can report a bug on launchpad against gnome-power-manager, but it is likely that your problem is only temporary and will disappear with updates.

If you still get the problem, you can revert the whitelist settings for the unity-panel (unless you still need to see some particular application there).

*BTW I have this problem in 11.10 as well; but I believe it is only temporary as it only appeared in the latest update I installed (so it will be gone before release).*