# How can I manually edit the unity top panel?

Tags: unity, panel, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get rid of double battery monitor status?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59718/how-do-i-get-rid-of-double-battery-monitor-status)

After the recent update of 11.10, I am left with two battery indicators, for some reason--the new one, with the options to show the remaining time and bring up the power settings, and the old one, which doesn't do anything when clicked. How can I manually edit the top panel listings to remove this artifact?

Comment: Well, I still wish I knew how to edit this panel manually. Maybe that won't fix this problem, but at least I'd have learned something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the one wich doesn't do a thing is the one of the login screen. But this happens to me as well. Just check if the bug has already been reported (should be), and if not, report it on launchpad yourself.
Ubuntu 11.10 is only in beta stage, wich means it's for testing purposes only and will still have lots of bugs.