# Why are no changes to the main menu in Unity possible?

Tags: 11.10, unity, menu

Why can't I add a menu item in the main menu or see an item property? Is Unity the culprit ?

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: What main menu? the Dash? the Launcher? what do you want to add?

Comment: @dupont Can you please clarify what you mean by "main menu"? You may take a look at [this question regarding proper terminology for Unity UI elements](http://askubuntu.com/q/10228/18612) so we may better understand what you're asking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yup, it's Unity. Assuming you're talking about the top bar (also known as the Unity Global Menu), you might find one or the other of these questions helpful:

- [How do I modify the Unity Global Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77648/how-do-i-modify-the-unity-global-menu)
- [How can I manually edit the unity top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59922/how-can-i-manually-edit-the-unity-top-panel)

If you're talking about the launcher (also Unity) you can add items to it by choosing "keep in launcher" while they're open.

Comment: no I talk about the main menu, the one we got in former Ubuntu release before Unity, 10.04.This menu was at the top left and a scroll down list opened with all the soft categories.like this one **http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_the_Ubuntu_Desktop_Menu_System**

Comment: That "main menu" is not on in Unity -- how did you restore it?

Comment: peharps a upgrade bug from 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10 but the main menu is still here ?