# Two battery indicator symbols, how do I get rid of one?

Tags: indicator

After upgrading to 11.10 I have two battery indicator symbols. They look similar but show different tooltips. (It's German language - one only shows "Laptop-Akku ist vollständig aufgeladen" (Laptop-akku fully loaded), the other offers a menu that can bring up the energy options. The second one seems to be the right one. The first one I want to get rid of, but don't know which program this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/833397) about this. It only shows when the unity panel is set to whitelist all applications in the system tray, and seems to be related to GNOME Power Manager having a fall back icon.

I don't know if it *will* indeed be fixed soon, but I would suggest either waiting a while to see if an update fixes it, or disabling the unity systray whitelist.

- [How do I set the panel whitelist back to the default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76215/how-do-i-set-the-panel-whitelist-back-to-the-default)

Comment: Found the open bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/833397

Answer (score 0):

you may use dconf editor, look after apps menu, and see indicator session

[image]

1st you may not see the battery indicator and your username/account session, then go back to dconf editor, check back the one you un-check just now, then log-out and log-in back.

Comment: Could you explain better, please?